# Having a paper published via both Conference Proceedings and via a refereed journal

Tags: soft-question, computer-science

Forgive me if this isn't the right place to pose this question. I do need guidance on this.

1. In 2018 I had submitted a paper to a refereed journal. It had gotten accepted for publication by said refereed journal modulo some minor revisions and I am in the process of revising it. I also had presented this result at the 2019 Symposium On The Theory Of Computing [STOC 2019] in June. So far so good at this point, plenty of papers have appeared in both the conference proceedings--to disseminate quickly, and then in polished revised form in a refereed journal a bit later.
2. Here is where my dilemma is. This past fall 2019 I also received an invitation to submit this same result to a special edition of STOC 2019, which will appear in the SIAM Journal Of Computing. I had said yes thinking that this was just like the Conference Proceedings, without realizing at that time, that there may be a moral dilemma. I am not sure if I would be double-publishing my paper, which I understand is a no-no.
3. I am not sure where to go from here. I explained the situation to both the editors of the refereed journal and to the committee that invited me to submit this result to the special edition of STOC 2019, but have not received guidance back.

So this is my question: What do I need to do. I want this paper to go into the refereed journal, as they were the ones who reviewed it first. I admit to not being that familiar with the rules of publishing in academic journals. Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: This seems simple: Withdraw your acceptance to the special edition of the *SIAM Journal Of Computing*. (I am assuming your Yes came after the submission to the refereed journal.)

Comment: Hi @JosephO'Rourke yes you are correct.

Comment: You might ask at a computer science site as well since the conference publication culture is a bit different in computer science and in math.

Answer (score 7):

It is not a good practice to publish the same paper twice, (or more). Except the publication on the arXiv (I have a strong opinion that ALL mathematical papers should be published on the arXiv). I can tell you what I do in similar circumstances. If I talk on a conference on a result which is sent to a journal, or is already published, and the conference publishes proceedings, I publish my TALK in the proceedings, but this is a different text from the paper itself.